# android:targetPackage cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

this might seem trivial but I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

I downloaded the sample app activityInstrumentation( from Android Studio **File** -> **import Sample**) and inside the testing project manifest I get an unresolved symbol for

android:targetPackage="com.example.android.activityinstrumentation".

After that I've created a manifest for my application and still there is an unresolved symbol on the attribute.

My application project dir and test project dir are:

*app/src/main/java/com/example/appname*

- where manifest has

  ```
  package="com.example.appname"
  ```

*app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/appname*

- where manifest has

  ```
  <manifest
  ...
  package="com.example.appname.tests"
  ...
  android:targetPackage="com.example.appname"
  ...
  </manifest>
  ```

Please help me sort this out. I don't know what else I can do: using a sample app to create a full fledged test project was my very last hope.

Comment: I have the same problem, but it doesn't seem to effect anything. All the tests run and are executed without any problems...

Comment: OT: Leo k I couldn't find any good documentation on testing automatically with AS, if know how to do that and have some time to spare, please pm. email is on bio.

Comment: Not sure how useful it is, but the AS testing documentation, such as it is http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support
I'm currently more interested in running tests on device. If you have tests that don't need Android API calls, or can be mocked then you can use the second link info. If you want to run tests without a device, but still use Android API you probably need to use the Robolectric library/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify android:targetPackage in instrumentation tag.

[http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/instrumentation-element.html
]

Comment: android:targetPackage
The application that the Instrumentation object will run against. An application is identified by the package name assigned in its manifest file by the <manifest> element.

I made a mistake when posting but the package name of my project is the same as the targetPackage test project. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing. Seems to be only false alert produced by the `lint` code inspection. When you run analysis (Analyze->Inspect code...) and open "Inspection" tab you can select the warning and mark it `Suppress for tag`. That will get rid of the warning.